# Simple doubt about partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm reading [Farlow's Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048667620X) and am trying to solve the following problem:

> [image]

The answer is:

> [image]

I don't understand how he comes up to this answer. We have the heat equation, so I guess $u_{tt}(x,0)=-\pi ^2 \sin (\pi  x)$ and then $u_t (x,0)=\alpha^2(- \pi ^2 \sin (\pi  x))$, I think this means that $u(x,t)$ is decreasing as $t\to \infty$ but what confuses me is that we only have that information for a small neighborhood $(x,0)$. How do we know that $u(x,t)\to 0$ as $t\to \infty$? Even the function he gives as an example doesn't seems to approach zero as $t\to \infty$.

**EDIT:** I think there is a typo in the answer, it should be $e^{-\alpha^2 t} \sin (\pi x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, $u_{xx}(x,0)=-\pi^2 \sin(\pi x)$. So now after a little time evolution, you have $u(x,0)$ plus a multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$ which is again a multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$. Therefore $u_{xx}(x,t)=-\pi^2 u(x,t)$ for all $t$. Then the PDE tells you $u_t(x,t)=-\alpha^2 \pi^2 u(x,t)$, which means that for each fixed $x$ you have exponential decay.

That "after a little time evolution" phrase is not rigorous, but it can be sorted out rigorously by substituting $u(x,t)=f(t) \sin(\pi x)$ into the PDE and then solving the resulting ODE for $f$.

I am not really even sure what the goal was with that second hint.

Comment: I still don't know what eigenfunctions/differential operators are. I am trying to learn PDE's on my own with Farlow's Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers and this example is from the very beginning of the book. Could you explain in a more elementary way?

Comment: @RedBanana The concept is still the same, but I rephrased without the jargon words.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that with the second hint, he meant: "Take a look at a function in which this happens" or something like that.

Comment: @RedBanana Maybe, except $\alpha^2$ is the wrong coefficient for the exponent. And so is $-\alpha^2$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, had a bit of trouble in life. But where did you get that "after a little time evolution, you have $u(x,0)$ plus a multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$"? Do you get to that from $u_{xx}(x,0)=-\pi^2 \sin(\pi x)$ and continuity?

Comment: @RedBanana At the intuitive level you just think of the displacement as being a multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$ because the time derivative is a multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$ at the beginning and then adding $h$ times that to $u(x,0)$ gives another multiple of $\sin(\pi x)$ again. But as I said in the answer, the rigorous explanation involves actually plugging the separable form into the equation.